# How to Mock file array using PowerMockito?

Tags: java, mockito, powermock

I have the below `static` method in my Configs class which I am trying to Mock using Powermockito.

```
Ln 1  public static method getConfigs(){
   2
   3  File[] files = new File(/tmp/dir/).listFiles();
   4   if (null == files) {
   5    return Collections.emptyMap();
   6   }
   7   return getData();
      }
```

And in my test class:

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(Configs.class)  
public class ConfigsTest {

@InjectMocks
Configs configs;

@Test
public void testGetConfigs() throws Exception {

  PowerMockito.mockStatic(Configs.class);
  Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
  map.put("data", "data");

  File file = PowerMockito.mock(File.class);
  File[] files = new File[] { new File("file") };

  PowerMockito.when(file.listFiles()).thenReturn(files);
  PowerMockito.when(configs.getDataMap()).thenReturn(map);

  Map data = secrets.getDataMap();
  Assert.assertNotNull(data);
}
```

Now, the issue is that the test fails at the IF condition, line 4. I tried several ways to mock and add value to the `file` object used in the null check. I need my tests to cover beyond the IF condition to meet sonar coverage. Please let me know how I could achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

I think it should be like this

```
PowerMockito.mockStatic(Configs.class);
PowerMockito.when(Configs.getConfigs()).thenReturn(map);
```

[powermock-static](https://github.com/powermock/powermock/wiki/Mockito#mocking-static-method)

Comment: I tried keeping just these lines and removed the code to mock files. But that didn't help. Still showing the same coverage. I believe the reason is files is somehow coming as null